# How to use SQL Server data locks on SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, locking

I would like some help with SQL Server locks, as I am having difficulty understanding how they work. The job is simple. I may have two orders coming in at the same time, or a split second difference, that try to allocate a certain amount of inventory on hand. The query takes already created order detail record and updates it with qty ordered in sufficient inventory is available. What I would like to be able to do  if the second order comes in with the same product request, it shouldn't over allocate, basically it should check IOH minus already allocated orders. So I'd like to prevent second order stepping on the first one and double allocating.

I've tried creating a two simple transactions running one with delay to see if the other one waits for the commit of the first. The second one timed out.

```
-- QOH IS ASSUMED TO BE 100
-- THIS IS THE 'SLOW' PROCESS

-- VARIABLES
DECLARE @QtyAvailable INT;
DECLARE @ID INT;
DECLARE @OrderQty INT;
DECLARE @ProcessID INT;
Declare @ProdID nchar(10);

SET @OrderQty = 20;
SET @ProcessID = 1;

-- LOCK HEADER RECORD AND CHECK ALLOCATION
begin transaction;
update alldetail set [exists]=0 where orderid=1;
select @QTYAVAILABLE = (select qty from locdet where locid='loc1' and prodid='prod1') - (select           isnull(sum(qtyall),0) from alldetail where locid='loc1' and prodid='prod1')

IF @QtyAvailable >= @OrderQty 
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
    PRINT 'Allocation passes, QTY Available before order = ' + CAST(@QTYAVAILABLE AS VARCHAR(20))
    PRINT 'Order QTY = ' + cast(@orderqty as varchar(20))
    update alldetail set [exists] = 1, qtyall=@OrderQty where orderid=1 and prodid='prod1' and locid='loc1';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Allocation FAILS, QTY Available = ' + CAST(@QTYAVAILABLE AS VARCHAR(20))
    update alldetail set [exists]=0, qtyall=0 where orderid=1 and locid='loc1' and prodid='prod1'       END
select @QTYAVAILABLE = (select qty from locdet where locid='loc1' and prodid='prod1') - (select   isnull(sum(qtyall),0) from alldetail where locid='loc1' and prodid='prod1');
PRINT 'QTY Available after order = ' + CAST(@QTYAVAILABLE AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' Time: ' +    cast(convert(time,GETDATE()) as char(50))
COMMIT transaction;
```

The second one is similar, but wihout timedelay, qty=15 and orderid=2

Answer (score 0):

Two thing fixed the issue. Correct datatable design with an index on the primary key. Another one was using with(rowlock) on the initial update statement.